# Existence of the Lebesgue measure, proof thereof.

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

On page 10 of [Stefan Grosskinsky's lecture notes](http://homepages.warwick.ac.uk/~masgav/teaching/notes06.pdf), Theorem 1.7 states the following.

There exists an unique Borel measure $\mu$ on $(\mathbb{R}, \mathcal{B})$ such that $\mu((a, b]) = b - a$ for all $a < b$ in $\mathbb{R}$.

The Borel measure claimed to exist is called the Lebesgue measure. In the proof, a set function is defined on the ring of half-open intervals, $$\mathcal{R} := \{\bigcup_{n=1}^{N} (a_n, b_n]: N \in \mathbb{N}, \forall n, a_n < b_n\}.$$ For a set $\bigcup_{n=1}^{N} (a_n, b_n]$ in $\mathcal{R}$ with disjoint intervals, define $$\mu(\bigcup_{n=1}^{N} (a_n, b_n]) := \sum_{n=1}^{N} (b_n - a_n).$$ Clearly this $\mu$ satisfies $\mu((a, b]) = b - a$. The proof then shows that $\mu$ is countably additive. We also know that $\sigma(\mathcal{R}) = \mathcal{B}$, and so by Caratheodory extension theorem, $\mu$ extends to a measure in $\mathcal{B}$.

My question is about the way we prove that $\mu$ is countably additive. In Grosskinsky's lecture notes, this is done by showing that $\mu$ is continuous from above at $\emptyset$. Since we also clearly have $\mu(A) < \infty$ for all $A \in \mathcal{R}$, this implies that $\mu$ is countably additive. However, I've managed to convince myself for the moment that, by defining $\mu$ differently in the first place, we can prove the countable additivity of $\mu$ directly, without resorting to the equivalence between continuity (under certain conditions) and countable additivity. Here it goes.

Define set function $\lambda$ for all unions (finite or countably infinite) of disjoint intervals, $$\lambda(\bigcup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} (a_n, b_n]) := \sum_{n \in \mathbb{N}} (b_n - a_n).$$ Note that $\lambda(\cdot)$ may be $\infty$. This definition is only slightly different from that of $\mu$ above, in that $\lambda$ is defined on possibly (countably) infinite unions of disjoint intervals, whereas $\mu$ is only defined on finite unions of disjoint intervals. We see that $\lambda$ also clearly satisfies $\lambda((a, b]) = b - a$. Moreover, $\lambda$ restricted to $\mathcal{R}$, which we call $\lambda|_{\mathcal{R}}$ for convenience, is the same as $\mu$. The point is that $\lambda$ is countably additive by definition. Consider disjoint sets $(A_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ in $\mathcal{R}$. The union $\bigcup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} A_n$ is precisely a possibly countably infinite union of disjoint intervals, since each $A_n$ is a finite union of disjoint intervals and the $A_n$ are mutually disjoint. That is to say, $$\bigcup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} A_n = \bigcup_{i \in \mathbb{N}} (c_i, d_i],$$ for some suitable choice of $c_i$ and $d_i$, where the $(c_i, d_i]$ are mutually disjoint. But by definition of $\lambda$, we have $$\lambda(\bigcup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} A_n) = \lambda(\bigcup_{i \in \mathbb{N}}(c_i, d_i]) = \sum_{i \in \mathbb{N}}(d_i - c_i) = \sum_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \lambda(A_n).$$ This is the statement that $\lambda$ is countably additive, as required.

My hunch is that this proof must be wrong, but I can't see what's wrong at the moment. Can you?

Comment: You have to prove that $\lambda$ is well-defined, i.e. that if $\bigcup_n (a_n, b_n] = \bigcup_n (c_n, d_n]$, then $\sum_n (b_n - a_n) = \sum_n (d_n -c_n)$. In proving this, you will actually prove a stronger statement than the countable additivity.

Comment: I've been thinking about this for a while and I don't see how it is so difficult to prove that $\lambda$ is well-defined. Also, what would be the stronger statement that I would be proving?

Comment: I can outline a proof that $\lambda$ is well-defined as follows. (1) Suppose $a < b$ and $c < d$, we call two intervals $(a, b]$ and $(c, d]$ separate if they are disjoint and either $b < c$ or $d < a$. (2) The representation $\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}(a_n, b_n]$ is unique (up to re-ordering of the intervals) if the intervals are separate. (3) $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(b_n - a_n)$ is therefore unique (and thus $\lambda$ well-defined) since all $(b_n - a_n)$ are  positive (and so we can re-order them in an infinite sum) and limits in $\mathbb{R}$ are unique.

Comment: To see that something nontrivial is going on here, have a lock at this question:http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/948571/how-is-this-mu-0-not-a-premeasure/948585#comment1953470_948585. I will elaborate on this later.

Comment: Thank you @PhoemueX, and sorry for the late reply. I've had a look at your link and I think I understand it, but I still can't relate that to this case. The question in your link is about $\mathbb{Q}$ and that's how Harald Hanche-Olsen could construct a countable union that breaks $\mu_0$. My case is $\mathbb{R}$, and I can't relate the information in your link to here.

Comment: Intuitively, the essence of the problem with $\mu_0$ in the question in your link is that it "over-measures" large intervals in $\mathbb{Q}$, because the naive measurement $\mu_0((a, b]) := b - a$ would "measure" all the irrational real number as well as the rationals inside (a, b], and in order to break $\mu_0$, we just need to have (countably) many small intervals whose union is a large interval, which is what Harald Hanche-Olsen did. But I don't have that problem here, $\mathbb{R}$ has no gaps in it and so $\lambda$ is not "over-measuring".