# Outer measure and Subadditivity

Tags: measure-theory

Consider $\{(a,b] \cap \mathbb{Q}:a\leq b, a,b \in \mathbb{Q}\}$, with $\tau((a,b] \cap \mathbb{Q})=b-a$, and $\mu$ the outer measure of $\mathbb{Q}$ generated by $\tau$. I want to determine $\mu(R)$, where $R$ is any subset contained in $\mathbb{Q}$, and I want to show that $\mu$ is not an extension of $\tau$ by showing that  $\tau$ is not $\sigma$-subadditive on $\{(a,b] \cap \mathbb{Q}:a\leq b, a,b \in \mathbb{Q}\}$.

I am thinking that since $R$ is a subset of $\mathbb{Q}$ and $\mathbb{Q}$ has outer measure zero, $R$ must also have outer measure zero.  Is this correct? I am having trouble showing that $\tau$ is not $\sigma$-subadditive. I want to show that there exists some $A \in \{(a,b] \cap \mathbb{Q}:a\leq b, a,b \in \mathbb{Q}\}$ with $A$ contained in $\cup B_n$ for some $B_n$ but $\tau(A)=b-a > \sum\tau( B_n).$ Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Similar (but not quite identical) question: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/948571/how-is-this-mu-0-not-a-premeasure